# In hadoop cluster adding new datanode

Tags: hadoop

I have setup 3 node cluster which is working fine. Now i want to add one more node to this cluster.I tried but new node is not adding to cluster. My question is where can I find exception msgs for such issue.
One more in new node if I start data-node daemon it will start but if I connect to cluster the name node is stopping data-node daemon. Because I guess some configuration or directory permission problem so how can I find out those errors ? which log file those errors are available?

Exception:--------------

```
013-06-14 18:20:33,987 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: NameNode up at: master/192.168.0.135:8020
2013-06-14 18:20:33,988 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Starting services required for active state
2013-06-14 18:20:34,371 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hdfs (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Log not rolled. Name node is in safe mode.
The reported blocks 0 needs additional 374 blocks to reach the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 374. Safe mode will be turned off automatically.
2013-06-14 18:20:34,371 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 8020, call org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.NamenodeProtocol.rollEditLog from 192.168.0.115:33532: error: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Log not rolled. Name node is in safe mode.
The reported blocks 0 needs additional 374 blocks to reach the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 374. Safe mode will be turned off automatically.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Log not rolled. Name node is in safe mode.
The reported blocks 0 needs additional 374 blocks to reach the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 374. Safe mode will be turned off automatically.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.rollEditLog(FSNamesystem.java:4433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.rollEditLog(NameNodeRpcServer.java:734)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.NamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.rollEditLog(NamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.NamenodeProtocolProtos$NamenodeProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(NamenodeProtocolProtos.java:8762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:898)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1689)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1687)
2013-06-14 18:21:34,395 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hdfs (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Log not rolled. Name node is in safe mode.
The reported blocks 0 needs additional 374 blocks to reach the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 374. Safe mode will be turned off automatically.
2013-06-14 18:21:34,395 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 4 on 8020, call org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.NamenodeProtocol.rollEditLog from 192.168.0.115:33534: error: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Log not rolled. Name node is in safe mode.
The reported blocks 0 needs additional 374 blocks to reach the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 374. Safe mode will be turned off automatically.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Log not rolled. Name node is in safe mode.
The reported blocks 0 needs additional 374 blocks to reach the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 374. Safe mode will be turned off automatically.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.rollEditLog(FSNamesystem.java:4433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.rollEditLog(NameNodeRpcServer.java:734)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.NamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.rollEditLog(NamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.NamenodeProtocolProtos$NamenodeProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(NamenodeProtocolProtos.java:8762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:898)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1689)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1687)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log files are usually in your `$HADOOP_HOME/logs`, `$HADOOP_HOME` is your hadoop install dir.

You can look into these two log files:

- `hadoop-USERNAME-namenode-HOSTNAME.log` in the node where your namenode is running
- `hadoop-USERNAME-datanode-HOSTNAME.log` which is in the node where you start the newly added datanode.

  `USERNAME` and `HOSTNAME` is the username you used to run hadoop, and the hostname of your node.

Comment: thanks i got. Now i shared exception by editing my question plz check above que

Comment: Your NameNode is able to start but before it goes out of "Safe Mode" it gives up.Looks like you have some permissions issue. Please check that you are setting permissions properly.